# Как вызвать рекурсивный метод от приватного поля?

Tags: c++

Допустим необходимо рекурсивно пройтись по бинарному дереву и метод работает от переданных в него узлов. Ну и собственно чтобы совершить полный проход надо подать на вход корень бинарного дерева.
Но корень идет как приватное поле класса и приходится писать публичный метод вызывающий рекурсивный проход от корня.
Думаю может корень поставить как значение по умолчанию, но может есть более правильный/простой способ?
Edit: требует чтобы поле корня было статическим, хотя у каждого дерева свое должно быть

Comment: Любые приватные переменные вы можете просто отдавать по значению.`тип_узла_дерева const * tree_root ( void ) const { return указатель_на_корень_дерева ; }` ничего страшного.

Comment: Ничего страшного в написании публичного метода для получения доступа к приватным полям нет. Это нормальная и даже рекомендуемая практика в ООП - поля пихать в приватную часть и давать к ним доступ через публичные методы. Как вариант №2 вы можете объявить дружественный класс/функцию и в них делать проход с доступом к публичным полям

Comment: А вообще рекомендую научится формировать мысли и прикреплять минимальный рабочий пример, чтобы все поняли, что вы от нас хотите. Правильно поставленный вопрос - половина ответа. Например в вашем вопросе абсолютно не ясно, в чем проблема приватности корня дерева и кто и зачем требует, чтобы это поле было статическим

Comment: Если не хочется открывать голожопые указатели - придумывайте  непрозрачный итератор для дерева, который можно было бы от него получить и использовать для обхода.  В крайнем случае процедура обхода дерева может быть "дружественной" классу дерева.